# Angular.js ngDialog box disappearance iOS devices Safari browser specific issue

Tags: javascript, iphone, angularjs, mobile-safari, ng-dialog

I am facing an issue where my ngDialog box disappears very quickly on my iOS devices. The dialog box is being displayed for 3 seconds on desktop system but disappears very quickly on iOS devices in Safari browser. On Chrome this works perfectly.

The code is posted here:

```
            var dialog = ngDialog.open({
                template: '<div><uib-alert type="success">' + message + '</uib-alert></div>',
                className: 'ngdialog-theme-default popup-custom-height',
                showClose: false,
                closeByNavigation: true,
                closeByDocument: false,
                plain: true
            });

            $timeout(function () {
                ngDialog.close(dialog.id);
            }, 3000);
```

I have also debugged the issue. However, this `ngDialog.close(...)` is being called after 3 seconds but before that somehow dialog box disappears from screen.

Comment: any answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not due to timeout or anything. There was global function which dismisses all dialog boxes so this is fixed.